# Tried ppa:oem-solutions-group/intel-ipu6 with thinkpad x1 carbon gen 10

Tags: 22.04, thinkpad

Anyone has any luck making the camera on this laptop work,

I've added `ppa:oem-solutions-group/intel-ipu6` and run `apt install libcamhal-ipu6ep0` but all I get in chrome is something like this
[image]

Comment: As side effect the `v4l2-relayd.service` takes up around 8G of memory

Comment: This describe the problem of support: https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/YvUKLbv%2FpOfbbeL+@pendragon.ideasonboard.com/
@SmCaterpillar solution might work for you:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1461869