# MIPI Webcam on Lenovo Thinkpad X1 carbon Gen 11 on Ubuntu 22.04 not fully working

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, webcam, camera

I have just installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my new X1 Carbon **Gen 11**. Everything seems to be working, except, unsurprisingly, the MIPI webcam. [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1461734/mipi-webcam-with-thinkpad-x1-gen10-not-working-with-ubuntu-22-04) addresses the same issue but for the X1 Carbon **Gen 10**. I followed all the instructions outlined in the solution below, specifically using dkms and also always went with the ipu6ep wherever I had a choice.

This almost works. After the command

```
sudo -E gst-launch-1.0 icamerasrc buffer-count=7 device-name=ov2740-uf ! video/x-raw,format=NV12,width=1280,height=720 ! v4l2sink device=${DEVICE}
```

the camera light switches on, indicating that *something* is happening. However on the terminal I see the following output:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
[07-04 16:03:18.568] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name OV2740_CJFLE23_ADL.aiqb
[07-04 16:03:18.568] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name OV2740_CJFLE23_ADL.aiqb
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock

(gst-launch-1.0:4105): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 16:03:18.628: Registering meta implementation 'GstCamerasrcMeta' without init function
[07-04 16:03:18.900] CamHAL[ERR] Poll: Device node fd 14 poll timeout.
[07-04 16:03:19.0] CamHAL[ERR] Poll: Device node fd 14 poll timeout.
[07-04 16:03:19.100] CamHAL[ERR] Poll: Device node fd 14 poll timeout.
[07-04 16:03:19.200] CamHAL[ERR] Poll: Device node fd 14 poll timeout.
[07-04 16:03:19.301] CamHAL[ERR] Poll: Device node fd 14 poll timeout.
[07-04 16:03:19.401] CamHAL[ERR] Poll: Device node fd 14 poll timeout.
[07-04 16:03:19.501] CamHAL[ERR] Poll: Device node fd 14 poll timeout.
[07-04 16:03:19.602] CamHAL[ERR] Poll: Device node fd 14 poll timeout.
[07-04 16:03:19.702] CamHAL[ERR] Poll: Device node fd 14 poll timeout.
[07-04 16:03:19.800] CamHAL[ERR] Poll: Device node fd 16 poll timeout.
[07-04 16:03:19.802] CamHAL[ERR] Poll: Device node fd 14 poll timeout.
[07-04 16:03:19.902] CamHAL[ERR] Poll: Device node fd 14 poll timeout.
[07-04 16:03:20.3] CamHAL[ERR] Poll: Device node fd 14 poll timeout.
[07-04 16:03:20.103] CamHAL[ERR] Poll: Device node fd 14 poll timeout.
[07-04 16:03:20.203] CamHAL[ERR] Poll: Device node fd 14 poll timeout.
[07-04 16:03:20.304] CamHAL[ERR] Poll: Device node fd 14 poll timeout.
[07-04 16:03:20.404] CamHAL[ERR] Poll: Device node fd 14 poll timeout.
[07-04 16:03:20.504] CamHAL[ERR] Poll: Device node fd 14 poll timeout.
[07-04 16:03:20.605] CamHAL[ERR] Poll: Device node fd 14 poll timeout.
[07-04 16:03:20.629] CamHAL[WAR] wait event time out, 1 requests processing, 6 requests in HAL
```

The last couple of lines are repeated every half second or so and the camera light stays on. However cheese is not able to detect the camera. I also tried to launch cheese with the command

```
cheese -d "Intel MIPI Camera"
```

and this does not help.

Is there anybody in a similar situation and got the MIPI Camera to work?

Comment: I have been fighting the very same fight myself today (but on a Dell 5680). I just got it working. IPU6 seems to also need "ivsc". Checking my dmesg, I see many "intel vsc not ready", followed by "vsc_ace ... recv firmware id" just before "intel-ipu6-isys0: All sensor registration completed". (Hoping this is a clue for you, or anyone else ending up here)

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lenovo has some instructions for Intel MIPI camera that you can try.

There is a known issue on Cheese that it can not support Intel MIPI camera via the v4l2loopback workaround.

It is better to use Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox to visit https://webcamtests.com/ to check your MIPI camera.