# ThinkPad X1 Yoga cam not working in Ubuntu 23.04, cannot build icamerasrc

Tags: software-installation, compiling, webcam, libraries

I bought a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Yoga Gen 7 with:

32 GiB RAM
  CPU: 12th Gen Intel Core i7-1260P x 16
  Mesa Intel Graphics (ADL GT2)
  SSD: 2 TB
  FHD camera system with 4 microphones
  3840x2400 Display which implies a MiPi camera as I       learned*****

and installed Ubuntu 23.04.

***** I wasn't able to detect the camera hardware with Linux or Windows. I found "MiPi" by research.

As far as I tested yet everything works well except the build in camera. I could not test the microphones yet.

It seems to be a well-known problem similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1461734/mipi-webcam-with-thinkpad-x1-gen10-not-working-with-ubuntu-22-04)

I tried to follow the described solution. Unfortunately the build of the icamerasrc.git fails because the prior installed libcamhal is not found. I am not very experiences with building and installing manually on my system, so I probably made beginner's mistakes, and any help is appreciated.

What I tried in detail:
First I installed Ubuntu 22.04. After it failed I tried Ubuntu 20.04.06 because some ThinkPads of this kind was sold with Ubuntu 20.04, but it failed again. Now I have Ubuntu 23.04, and I am still trying to get it work.

I realized that there are some packages needed that are not installed by default like dkms and git. Also I assume working with sudo should work, but since I don't know what causes the problem, I tried installing it as root. Then I got some problems that where caused by a path which contained spaces. I came from macOS and got surprised. Anyway I eliminated the unnecessary spaces.

What I actually did at last was this:

```
sudo su  
mkdir -p /media/data/shared/Installer/Linux/avp/Lenovo_ThinkPad_X1_Yoga_Gen_7_internal_Cam/  
cd /media/data/shared/Installer/Linux/avp/Lenovo_ThinkPad_X1_Yoga_Gen_7_internal_Cam/  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get upgrade  
sudo apt-get install git build-essential dkms cmake libdrm-dev v4l-utils libexpat-dev automake libtool libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
```

```
Hinweis: »libexpat1-dev« wird an Stelle von »libexpat-dev« gewählt.
```

```
git clone https://github.com/intel/ipu6-drivers.git  
cd ipu6-drivers  
git clone https://github.com/intel/ivsc-driver.git  
cp -r ivsc-driver/backport-include ivsc-driver/drivers ivsc-driver/include .  
rm -rf ivsc-driver  
cd ..  
git clone https://github.com/intel/ipu6-camera-bins.git  
git clone https://github.com/intel/ipu6-camera-hal.git  
git clone https://github.com/intel/icamerasrc.git  
cd icamerasrc/  
git checkout icamerasrc_slim_api  
cd ..  
cp ipu6-camera-hal/build.sh .  
cd ipu6-drivers  
sudo dkms add .  
sudo dkms autoinstall ipu6-drivers/0.0.0  
cd ..  
sudo cp -r ipu6-camera-bins/include/* /usr/include/  
sudo cp -r ipu6-camera-bins/lib/* /usr/lib/  
sudo ./build.sh
```

```
Libraries have been installed in:  
   /media/data/shared/Installer/Linux/avp/Lenovo_ThinkPad_X1_Yoga_Gen_7_internal_Cam/out/install/lib/gstreamer-1.0
###############   build_icamerasrc  OK   #############
```

```
sudo cp -r ./out/install/include/* /usr/include  
sudo cp -r ./out/install/lib/* /usr/lib  
sudo cp -r ./out/install/share/* /usr/share  
cd icamerasrc  
export CHROME_SLIM_CAMHAL=ON  
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig"  
sudo ./autogen.sh
```

```
Building with libcamhal  
checking for libcamhal... no  
configure: error: Cannot find libcamhal pkgconfig  
configure failed
```

Though I just installed ipu6-camera-hal it is not recognized as libcamhal. Is this something different? Did I forget an important step? ./out contains among other things:

```
out/install/lib/libhal_adaptor.so  
out/install/lib/libgsticamerainterface-1.0.so  
out/install/lib/ipu_mtl/libcamhal.so  
out/install/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgsticamerasrc.so  
out/install/lib/ipu_tgl/libcamhal.so  
out/install/lib/ipu_adl/libcamhal.so
```

Aren't these the libs which are just installed by copying them to `/usr/lib`?

As requested here are some outputs:

```
$ sudo dmesg|grep ipu6
[    3.935647] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.935884] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Device 0x465d (rev: 0x2)
[    3.935906] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: physical base address 0x603c000000
[    3.935908] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: mapped as: 0x000000000721f56d
[    3.935954] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU in secure mode
[    3.935956] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU secure touch = 0x0
[    3.935957] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU camera mask = 0xff
[    3.952548] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPC reset done
[    3.952552] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: cpd file name: intel/ipu6ep_fw.bin
[    3.953693] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: FW version: 20230102
[    3.962943] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Device 0x465d (rev: 0x2)
[    3.962966] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: physical base address 0x603c000000
[    3.962968] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: mapped as: 0x00000000d3a0191d
[    3.963175] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU in secure mode
[    3.963177] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU secure touch = 0x0
[    3.963179] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU camera mask = 0xff
[    3.968141] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPC reset done
[    3.968144] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: cpd file name: intel/ipu6ep_fw.bin
[    3.968273] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: FW version: 20230102
[    3.971715] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Device 0x465d (rev: 0x2)
[    3.971737] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: physical base address 0x603c000000
[    3.971739] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: mapped as: 0x000000000721f56d
[    3.971777] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU in secure mode
[    3.971779] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU secure touch = 0x0
[    3.971780] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU camera mask = 0xff
[    3.974112] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPC reset done
[    3.974115] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: cpd file name: intel/ipu6ep_fw.bin
[    3.974204] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: FW version: 20230102
[    3.982624] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Device 0x465d (rev: 0x2)
[    3.982640] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: physical base address 0x603c000000
[    3.982642] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: mapped as: 0x00000000d3a0191d
[    3.982680] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU in secure mode
[    3.982682] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU secure touch = 0x0
[    3.982683] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU camera mask = 0xff
[    3.987948] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPC reset done
[    3.987951] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: cpd file name: intel/ipu6ep_fw.bin
[    3.988080] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: FW version: 20230102
[    3.991085] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Device 0x465d (rev: 0x2)
[    3.991101] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: physical base address 0x603c000000
[    3.991103] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: mapped as: 0x000000005eca06cc
[    3.991145] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU in secure mode
[    3.991146] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU secure touch = 0x0
[    3.991148] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU camera mask = 0xff
[    3.993267] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPC reset done
[    3.993270] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: cpd file name: intel/ipu6ep_fw.bin
[    3.993351] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: FW version: 20230102
[    4.000086] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Device 0x465d (rev: 0x2)
[    4.000108] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: physical base address 0x603c000000
[    4.000110] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: mapped as: 0x000000005cc98771
[    4.000150] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU in secure mode
[    4.000152] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU secure touch = 0x0
[    4.000153] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU camera mask = 0xff
[    4.005098] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPC reset done
[    4.005100] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: cpd file name: intel/ipu6ep_fw.bin
[    4.005171] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: FW version: 20230102
[    4.016569] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Device 0x465d (rev: 0x2)
[    4.016584] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: physical base address 0x603c000000
[    4.016586] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: mapped as: 0x00000000d3a0191d
[    4.016618] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU in secure mode
[    4.016619] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU secure touch = 0x0
[    4.016621] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU camera mask = 0xff
[    4.020530] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPC reset done
[    4.020532] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: cpd file name: intel/ipu6ep_fw.bin
[    4.020631] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: FW version: 20230102
[    4.036195] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Device 0x465d (rev: 0x2)
[    4.036209] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: physical base address 0x603c000000
[    4.036210] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: mapped as: 0x000000005eca06cc
[    4.036235] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU in secure mode
[    4.036236] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU secure touch = 0x0
[    4.036237] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU camera mask = 0xff
[    4.040313] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPC reset done
[    4.040316] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: cpd file name: intel/ipu6ep_fw.bin
[    4.040424] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: FW version: 20230102
[    4.052389] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Device 0x465d (rev: 0x2)
[    4.052424] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: physical base address 0x603c000000
[    4.052426] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: mapped as: 0x000000000721f56d
[    4.052472] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU in secure mode
[    4.052475] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU secure touch = 0x0
[    4.052477] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU camera mask = 0xff
[    4.054276] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPC reset done
[    4.054279] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: cpd file name: intel/ipu6ep_fw.bin
[    4.054385] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: FW version: 20230102
[    4.079801] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Device 0x465d (rev: 0x2)
[    4.079830] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: physical base address 0x603c000000
[    4.079832] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: mapped as: 0x00000000d3a0191d
[    4.079898] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU in secure mode
[    4.079899] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU secure touch = 0x0
[    4.079901] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU camera mask = 0xff
[    4.083581] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPC reset done
[    4.083584] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: cpd file name: intel/ipu6ep_fw.bin
[    4.083661] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: FW version: 20230102
[    4.147389] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Device 0x465d (rev: 0x2)
[    4.147410] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: physical base address 0x603c000000
[    4.147411] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: mapped as: 0x00000000d3a0191d
[    4.147472] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU in secure mode
[    4.147475] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU secure touch = 0x0
[    4.147476] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU camera mask = 0xff
[    4.149845] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPC reset done
[    4.149848] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: cpd file name: intel/ipu6ep_fw.bin
[    4.150028] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: FW version: 20230102
[    4.191684] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Device 0x465d (rev: 0x2)
[    4.191708] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: physical base address 0x603c000000
[    4.191710] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: mapped as: 0x0000000002ee22b0
[    4.191756] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU in secure mode
[    4.191758] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU secure touch = 0x0
[    4.191759] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU camera mask = 0xff
[    4.193603] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPC reset done
[    4.193605] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: cpd file name: intel/ipu6ep_fw.bin
[    4.193716] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: FW version: 20230102
[    4.262608] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Device 0x465d (rev: 0x2)
[    4.262621] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: physical base address 0x603c000000
[    4.262622] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: mapped as: 0x0000000002ee22b0
[    4.262722] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU in secure mode
[    4.262725] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU secure touch = 0x0
[    4.262727] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU camera mask = 0xff
[    4.264803] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPC reset done
[    4.264805] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: cpd file name: intel/ipu6ep_fw.bin
[    4.264943] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: FW version: 20230102
[    4.299846] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Device 0x465d (rev: 0x2)
[    4.299857] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: physical base address 0x603c000000
[    4.299859] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: mapped as: 0x00000000c6ca14e3
[    4.299888] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU in secure mode
[    4.299891] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU secure touch = 0x0
[    4.299892] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU camera mask = 0xff
[    4.301706] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPC reset done
[    4.301707] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: cpd file name: intel/ipu6ep_fw.bin
[    4.301837] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: FW version: 20230102
[    4.319503] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Device 0x465d (rev: 0x2)
[    4.319523] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: physical base address 0x603c000000
[    4.319525] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: mapped as: 0x00000000cf4333ff
[    4.319564] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU in secure mode
[    4.319565] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU secure touch = 0x0
[    4.319567] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU camera mask = 0xff
[    4.321381] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPC reset done
[    4.321382] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: cpd file name: intel/ipu6ep_fw.bin
[    4.321488] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: FW version: 20230102
[    4.323547] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Found supported sensor INT3474:01
[    4.323651] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Connected 1 cameras
[    4.324616] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Sending BOOT_LOAD to CSE
[    4.333343] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Sending AUTHENTICATE_RUN to CSE
[    4.401681] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: CSE authenticate_run done
[    4.401698] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU6-v3 driver version 1.0
[    4.403190] intel-ipu6-isys intel-ipu6-isys0: bind ov2740 5-0036 nlanes is 2 port is 1
[    4.411593] intel-ipu6-isys intel-ipu6-isys0: All sensor registration completed.
[    4.411836] intel-ipu6-psys intel-ipu6-psys0: pkg_dir entry count:8
[    4.411955] intel-ipu6-psys intel-ipu6-psys0: psys probe minor: 0
[    7.312145] intel-ipu6-isys intel-ipu6-isys0: isys port open ready failed -16
[    7.312152] intel-ipu6-isys intel-ipu6-isys0: Device close failure: -16
[    8.460580] intel-ipu6-isys intel-ipu6-isys0: isys port open ready failed -16
[    8.460618] intel-ipu6-isys intel-ipu6-isys0: Device close failure: -16
[213694.863767] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU in secure mode
[257080.442282] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU in secure mode
```

```
$ lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4621] (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:46a6] (rev 0c)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake Innovation Platform Framework Processor Participant [8086:461d] (rev 02)
00:05.0 Multimedia controller [0480]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:465d] (rev 02)
00:06.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x4 Controller #0 [8086:464d] (rev 02)
00:07.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root P[edit] ort #0 [8086:466e] (rev 02)
00:07.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #2 [8086:462f] (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor Gaussian & Neural Accelerator [8086:464f] (rev 02)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Platform Monitoring Technology [8086:467d] (rev 01)
00:0d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller [8086:461e] (rev 02)
00:0d.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0 [8086:463e] (rev 02)
00:0d.3 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI #1 [8086:466d] (rev 02)
00:12.0 Serial controller [0700]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Integrated Sensor Hub [8086:51fc] (rev 01)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller [8086:51ed] (rev 01)
00:14.2 RAM memory [0500]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Shared SRAM [8086:51ef] (rev 01)
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi [8086:51f0] (rev 01)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:51e8] (rev 01)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 [8086:51e9] (rev 01)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller [8086:51e0] (rev 01)
00:19.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:51c5] (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51b8] (rev 01)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH eSPI Controller [8086:5182] (rev 01)
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller [8086:51c8] (rev 01)
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller [8086:51a3] (rev 01)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller [8086:51a4] (rev 01)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller PM9A1/PM9A3/980PRO [144d:a80a]
08:00.0 Wireless controller [0d40]: Intel Corporation XMM7560 LTE Advanced Pro Modem [8086:7560] (rev 01)
```

Comment: What's your `sudo dmesg | grep ipu6` output?

Comment: Please append your `lspci -nn`

Comment: Check out this MIPI doc: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IntelMIPICamera . There's some required packages in a PPA

Comment: thx. for the fast reactions. I added the dmesg and lspci outputs above. If that isn't the prefered way, here, please let me know.
I'll check the wiki page.

Comment: @r-a regarding the wiki: I did not find a MiPi driver in any repository. Perhaps I did not search correctly. E. g.: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oem-solutions-group/intel-ipu6; sudo apt install libcamhal0 -> E: Paket libcamhal0 kann nicht gefunden werden.
Same result for libcamhal and ipu6-camera-hal.

Comment: Oh right, that's for 22.04

Comment: I tried it with 20 and 22 and 23 with the same result, as far as I could see. If I have to switch back to 22.04, I will do so, but I don't know how to get it work with 22.04, neither.

Comment: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=402740
This seems to have the same controller as you do and is solved, has ipu6 instructions

Comment: What I don't understand most is that above "./build.sh" works up to "build_icamerasrc OK" which includes ipu6-camera-hal. And after that "./autogen.sh" results in "Cannot find libcamhal pkgconfig". What am I missing?

Comment: I'll try the mint solutionl.

Comment: pkgconfig in PPA is a .pc file in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig (`libcamhal-dev`)

Comment: I tried the Mint solution. As far as I understand they basically tried some things, then Mint published an update witch included the solution. I installed that Mint version, updated everything and since that did not help, tried the intel oem repository among other things without luck.
Then a friend found an article that mentioned at least kernel 6.
So I reinstalled Ubuntu 22.04.3 which has kernel 6.2.0.34 at found a working solution. I add the details above in the issue description.

Comment: Could you publish your hardware probe now that it works? `sudo apt install hw-probe`,  `sudo -E hw-probe -all -upload` (Post output link)

Comment: can't insert line feeds here.  // $ sudo -E hw-probe -all -upload //
Probe for hardware ... Ok // 
Reading logs ... Ok // 
WARNING: Unknown vendor 'CEB3' // 
Uploaded to DB, Thank you! // 
Probe URL: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=56d18c9f8a

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Ubuntu 22.04.3. It includes the latest Linux kernel 6.2.0.34.
2. Install all software updates that are offered by the Software Updater.
3. Run the following commands in a terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt upgrade
   sudo apt full-upgrade
   sudo apt install linux-modules-ipu6-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-modules-ivsc-generic-hwe-22.04
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oem-solutions-group/intel-ipu6
   sudo apt install libcamhal0 v4l2loopback-dkms v4l2-relayd v4l-utils vlc
   sudo reboot
   ```

Now you can use VLC with the camera as a recording device.

Comment: I tried this using Mint (ubuntu 22.04 upstream) on a Surface Pro 8. It recognizes the camera (what it's a win for now, first time that happens), but I didn't get any preview on Cheese or Google Meet.
And the laptop started to heat up in a unusual way.