Looking for an Ubuntu image for ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 12
I've recently got my brand new ThinkPad X11 Carbon Gen 12. Initially, I was going to order it with Ubuntu 22.04, but this option was unavailable in my region, so I ordered it with Windows 11 Pro, removed it and install Ubuntu.
Almost everything worked as expected from the box, including, surprisingly, 5G. The only issue was that Intel MIPI camera is not working. I've found out that that's a very common problem which affects all modern ThinkPads and many other laptops. This laptop is officially certified for Ubuntu 22.04 and there is a special OEM build with OEM kernel which, I believe, must work with the webcam properly.
Unfortunately, I couldn't find any ways how to get an image of this OEM Ubuntu. If I enter my serial number on support.lenovo.com I only can download several versions of Windows. Does anyone know how to get this very special version of Ubuntu?
P.S. I know what there is a workaround for MIPI cameras on Linux but I want something more "official".

why not try 24.04 with a live USB to see if that fixes it.

also possibly related https://askubuntu.com/questions/1461734/mipi-webcam-with-thinkpad-x1-gen10-not-working-with-ubuntu-22-04

@graham I've tried 24.04 and it's not fixed yet. As far as I know it fixed in kernel 6.10 which is still not delivered to 22.04 or 24.04. I know about the workaround you're referring to, and I've tried it in fact but I got many issues with those Intel repositories (broken trackpad, etc.).
